# Get list of google web fonts using XML

Tags: php, html, xml, fonts

I have a list of google web fonts in this file: http://phat-reaction.com/googlefonts.php?format=xml
Or say this format and so on...

```
<font>
    <font-family>
      <![CDATA[font-family: 'Abel', sans-serif;]]>
    </font-family>
    <font-name>
      <![CDATA[Abel]]>
    </font-name>
    <css-name>
      <![CDATA[Abel]]>
    </css-name>
  </font>
  <font>
    <font-family>
      <![CDATA[font-family: 'Abril Fatface', cursive;]]>
    </font-family>
    <font-name>
      <![CDATA[Abril Fatface]]>
    </font-name>
    <css-name>
      <![CDATA[Abril+Fatface]]>
    </css-name>
  </font>
  <font>
    <font-family>
      <![CDATA[font-family: 'Aclonica', sans-serif;]]>
    </font-family>
    <font-name>
      <![CDATA[Aclonica]]>
    </font-name>
    <css-name>
      <![CDATA[Aclonica]]>
    </css-name>
  </font>
```

Is there anyway using which I can extract only the css-name using the file? 
Like, I will want a like

```
  "Aclonica",
  "Allan",
  "Annie+Use+Your+Telescope",
  "Anonymous+Pro",
  "Allerta+Stencil",
```

I was thinking of some wildcard search and replace using Notepad++ or Dreamweaver.

Comment: [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) might be of some assistance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excavation...

```
<?php

  $url = 'http://phat-reaction.com/googlefonts.php?format=xml';
  $xml = simplexml_load_file($url, null, LIBXML_NOCDATA);

  foreach($xml->font as $font)
    $fonts[] = $font->{'css-name'};
  echo implode('<br/>', $fonts);
```